# How to get selected number after decimal point

Tags: c#, .net

I have a double value for Example

```
0.0070
0.100
0.040
```

and I want output of above numbers as follows

```
70
100
40
```

Please guide me
Thanks

Comment: Why is that 70, and not 7 (or 700?)

Comment: Do you need the trailing zeros? I can't see how that would be possible...

Comment: You problem is ill-stated and StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Show what you've tried so far and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

In theory this would be the way to do it

```
double number = 0.0070
string num = number.ToString();           //Convert to string
int index = num.IndexOf('.') + 1;         //Find the decimal
string trunc = num.Substring(index);      //Get rid of everything before it
trunc.TrimStart('0');                     //Get rid of leading zeros
double result = Convert.ToDouble(trunc);  //Convert back to double
```

**However**, C# does not respect trailing zeros in numerical values so as soon as you say `0.0070` into a double it is truncated to `0.007`

Comment: This will give you `70` - no, it won't.

Comment: It'd be more helpful to say what's wrong with the answer or suggest an edit than just say it's wrong. Be constructive

Comment: As Rowland Shaw and Michael McMullin have stated - it is impossible given current description of problem.

Comment: You are correct because C# does not respect trailing zeros in numerical values. I forgot. However, this was not stated in either of the comments that you reference and you could have simply said that in the first comment on my post.

Comment: But you post the code. Don't you try to execute it before posting? The only way the problem can be solved if original values are given as strings, not double.

Comment: trunc.TrimStart('0');  is removing leading zeros but as I stated C# removes trailing zeros and there is nothing you can do about that

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getTheNumberAfterDecimalPoint(double number)
{
    string numberInString = Convert.ToString(number);
    if(numberInString.Contains('.'))
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(numberInString.Substring('.')[1]);
    }
    return Convert.ToInt32(number);
}
```